# Is there a posibillity to look for a string in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, chatbot

I am trying to make a simple chatbot, and I want to use a dictionary. The user enters a question and the program looks for the input in the dictionary. If the string is in one of the keys, the program has to print the value.
But even if there are more than one possible awnsers, it should all print them.

Is there a posibillity to do this?

Comment: can you share the code you tried so far? We can help you in fixing your code

Comment: Yes. What specific problem do you have doing this? Why do you want to use a dict when you do not know how to solve your task with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can either look for 100% matches with the question by using the dictionary key.

```
>>> yourdict = {"What is your name?": "Einstein"}
>>> question = "What is your name?"
>>> print(yourdict[question])
'Einstein'
```

Alternatively, if you want partially matches with the key a dict is probably not the best data structure, as you have to compare the new question string with every existing question string, compute a similarity value and save the best match.